# Disable SSL Certificate Validation on Grpc.Core Channel

Tags: c#, grpc

I'd like to call into a `gRPC` service from a .NET Framework app using the `Grpc.Core` package. In .NET Core there's a way in the `Grpc.Net` package to disable SSL certificate validation:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://127.0.0.1:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions() { HttpClient = httpClient });
```

Is there a way to do the same using the Channel constructor directly:

```
Channel channel = new Channel($"{host.AddressList.First().ToString()}", 5001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure, new[]
{
   // new ChannelOptions(something here)           
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the ChannelCredentials.Insecure option allow you to communicate (at your ownr risk) without any SSL Certification?

Comment: Grpc.Insecure will cause the client to not just skip SSL verification, but to not use SSL at all, i.e. to use plain text.

Comment: Relevant feature request on github with some comments as for what can be done: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20430

Comment: Were you able to solve this?